# Xcode 7 - linker command failed with exit code 1 for Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase

Today when I updated my Firebase version to the most recent version (v2.4.1) I started receiving the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Firebase", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_TEDFirebase in TEDFirebase.o
  objc-class-ref in MessageListTableViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in ChatViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in EndUserAgreementViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in ProfileViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in MapsViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_Firebase", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TEDFirebase in TEDFirebase.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

These errors did not exist prior to the update. I am using Cocoapods to add the framework to the project. I've been searching online for a few hours trying every trick in the book (changing lot of build settings, "other linker flags", "framework search paths", "library search paths", etc.). I've looked at most every answer on Stack Overflow, but none of them resolve the issue. I'm thinking that this issue is purely with Firebase, but I'm not entirely sure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

If it helps, I am using Xcode 7.0 and my build target is iOS 8.3.

Comment: Try cleaning and then re-building.

Comment: I've done this multiple times, both in the past few days and just not, but no luck. I still get the exact same errors.

Comment: I would delete all of your Pods and try a fresh pod install.

Comment: I had already done this as well, multiple times. At this point, my only option was to revert to an older version of Firebase (2.3.3) where there are no issues. This old version builds fine with no warnings or errors, but it does not allow the use of bitcode, which is a major downside.

Comment: Are you enabling Bitcode?

Comment: I do not have bitcode enabled, because some other APIs I use are not supporting it yet.